# Запросы с in объединение. postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста. Можно ли как то объединить два SQL запроса? Возможно есть какие то идеи? Думаю, надо как то на входе разложить имена и адресы, но как не понятно и что дальше с этим делать.

```
 Select concat(trim(name),'.',dns_name) as FQDN, Address
 from database
 where  lower(name) in ('name1','name2','nameN') 

 Select concat(trim(name),'.',dns_name) as FQDN, Address
 from database
 where  address in ('address1','address2','addressN')
```

Comment: *Можно ли как то объединить два SQL запроса?* A что надо получить? объединение (UNION)? пересечение (INTERSECT)? что-то ещё?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, если речь идет о том, чтобы вместо двух запросов использовать один

```
select 
    concat(
        trim(name), 
        '.', 
        dns_name
    ) as FQDN, 
    Address 
from 
      database 
where 
    lower(name) in ('name1', 'name2', 'nameN') 
    or
    address in ('address1', 'address2', 'addressN')
```